# Factory de objetos relativos a persistencia local no Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Na aplicação que estou desenvolvendo usando o Swift, preciso ter acesso a uma entidade de dado persistido localmente, este entidade será construída através de um Factory com base em dados obtidos provavelmente por uma requisição e retorno em JSON, através de um processo de autenticação em um servidor remoto e assim armazenada localmente para evitar constantes consultas.

Como deve ser feita tal persistência local?

Comment: Utilize o coredata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É recomendado o uso do CoreData para armazenar os dados no device localmente. De semelhante forma, pode ser utilizado o FMDB, ou dependendo da necessidade, caso forem poucos dados à serem armazenados, pode ser utilizar o NSUserDefault.

Nesse site possui um tutorial divido em quarto partes bem detalhadas: [Core Data in Swift](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/core-data-in-swift-tutorial-part-1/)

Espero ajuda-lo

Comment: Teria algum exemplo para o @Delfino utilizar?

Comment: @David coloquei um link de tutorial, obrigado por lembrar

Comment: @David, o projeto foi uma prova de conceito para uma proposta, havia alguns dados que seriam lidos em um qrcode, uma vez obtido, este seriam enviados a um servidor que retornariam informações mais detalhadas, portanto tais informações seriam pouco alteradas no decorrer do uso, e poderiam ser cacheada, retornando apenas se ouve alteração desde a ultima consulta.